# Examples to explain what Ruby metaprogramming is

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

The term *metaprogamming* confuses me. Words like "programs that write programs" isn't helping at all, and I could not find good examples. I only have a vague idea that it adds methods to class definitions. But many other languages can do that, e.g., Objective-C has `Method swizzling` (by changing [Objective-C Runtime](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/objective-c_runtime#//apple_ref/c/func/method_getImplementation)).

Why does Ruby emphasize metaprogramming so much? Can someone give me some examples of metaprogamming in Ruby? What is it used for? What kind of problems does it solve?

Comment: Duckduckgo for “Ruby DSL.” IMSO, it’s mostly emphasized for extensive DSL abilities, e.g. Rails is 90% DSL.

Comment: There are a million resources on the internet which explain meta-programming. With such a generic question as "please show me an example of it", I fail to see how a random StackOverflow answer will be more useful than the vast other material online.

Comment: Can you recommend some links and I may just close my question ?

Comment: "Why does Ruby emphasize metaprogramming so much?" -- That's a subjective question. Ruby provides the tools to use metaprogramming techniques, but the language itself does not "emphasise" anything. Certain libraries/frameworks, written by opinionated authors, make heavy use of these tools. This is arguably a good thing (e.g. in rails, where there are model methods dynamically created for each database column) and arguably a bad thing (e.g. confusing/unnecessary use of `method_missing` madness).

Comment: "Can someone give me some examples of metaprogamming in Ruby? What is it used for?" -- `define_method`, `class_eval`, `respond_to?`, `method_missing`, `superclass`, `instance_eval`, `instance_exec`, ....... Google any of these terms and you'll find many use cases. I general, the idea is to increase the code's flexibility and auto-generate boilerplate code/

Comment: @TomLord: Even more widely-used than those: `attr_reader`.

Answer (score 2):

You should look at some resources on `method_missing`. Here is a good example of using it to make [dynamic methods](https://technicalpickles.com/posts/using-method_missing-and-respond_to-to-create-dynamic-methods). You can also see some of the [shortfalls and things to remember](https://www.pluralsight.com/blog/software-development/7-deadly-sins-of-ruby-metaprogramming). Personally, I seldom use metaprogramming for my day in day out work. A good reason for using it might be to create an interface or a DSL for a library. You may also be better served by looking at the theme of creating interfaces in general, and you will learn things about metaprogramming along the way.

Edit: I didn't answer all of the questions.

I can't speak for everyone in the ruby community, but it is quite cool in principal, kind of scary in practice, queue up the quote from Peter Parker's uncle. Pretty much existing class is modifiable at anytime in ruby. [Monkeypatching](https://spin.atomicobject.com/2017/12/29/monkey-patching-refinements/) is another dangerous thing you can do. Essentially, ruby classes aren't final. You can open them back up and write to them. Think about in javascript how you can write to an Array class's prototype to create more functions directly on an array.